# Processing two different submit button requests with one Spring MVC controller class

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have two submit buttons in thymeleaf template. I want it to submit it to 2 different actions in the same controller. I did the request mapping like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/directBind",  params={"send"})
public String send(Model model, @ModelAttribute(value="directBind") DirectBind directBind){

@RequestMapping(value="/directBind", params={"addPolicy"})
public String addPolicy(final DirectBind directBind, Model model){
```

Two input buttons in html:

```
 <input id="send"  type="submit" value="send" name="send" class="btn btn-success finish" data-loading-text="Sent!"/>

 <input type="submit"  name="addPolicy" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left: 1rem; margin-bottom: 1rem;"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span> </input>
```

Form :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="ui form" th:object="${directBind}" th:action="@{/send}" method="post"  style="padding:0 10px;">
```

Its submitting the form only to send action.

Answer (score 1):

I infer, you intent is to use one spring controller to process submit actions from two submit buttons.

- You can use same name and different value attribute for the two html input button`s. The buttons name and value attribute are sent to controller as request parameter. This will allow the controller to identify which button was clicked and take appropriate action.

```html
    <input id="send_id"  type="submit" name="action" value="send"/>
    <input id="addPolicy_id"  type="submit" name="action" value="addPolicy"/>
```

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/directBind")
    public String doExecute(@RequestParam("action") String action, Model model, @ModelAttribute(value="directBind") DirectBind directBind){
    if (action=="send"){
    //do something
    send();
    }
    if (action=="addPolicy"){
    //do something
    addPolicy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue. I used "directBind" in form action attribute and used param discriminator in the request mapping. It worked!